# Auto generated test class ContractCerifierTest.java fails to compile - not a statement

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Following this guide: [baeldung.com Spring Cloud Contract Intro](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-contract)

I have created the following `BaseTestClass`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
public class BaseTestClass extends RestAssuredMockMvc {


    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder
                = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder);
    }
}
```

And my stub is defined as follows:

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    name("contract_update")
    request {
        method 'PUT'
        url '/v1/xxxx'
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.twitter-places-analyzer.v1+json'
        }
        body(file("update_request.json"))
    }
    response {
        status OK()
        body(file("update_response.json"))
    }
}
```

When performing `mvn clean install` the auto-genereted class `ContractVerifierTest` is as follows:

```
public class ContractVerifierTest {

    @Test
    public void validate_contract_update() throws Exception {
        // given:
            MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.twitter-places-analyzer.v1+json")
                    .body(new String(fileToBytes(this, "contract_update_request_update_request.json")));

        // when:
            ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                    .put("/v1/xxxx");

        // then:
            assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
        // and:
            String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
            null;
    }

}
```

Notice the strange `null;` there.
I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project xxx-web: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxx/git/xxx/xxx-web/target/generated-test-sources/contracts/org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/tests/ContractVerifierTest.java:[36,25] not a statement
```

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? Also you don't need a standalone setup of your starting the whole context, you can use the webAppContext and you don't need autoconfiguremessageverifier cause you're not using messaging.

Comment: plugin version is :`2.1.3.RELEASE`. Thanks for the tips about the redundant configuration. I will try to make the changes and see if it helps.

Comment: You can also add the application/json content type on the response side

Comment: Hello @Nom1fan This might be a bug; could you please file an issue at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues along with a minimal, reproduceable sample?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek I apologize, I've already moved past this issue and unfortunately after trying so many things I am not entirely sure why the issue was caused and what resolved it.

Comment: Ok, I'm happy it's working then.